# Insufficient Permission Google API after Revoking

Tags: google-analytics, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

I have currently created user oauth login using google+.

```
<button class="g-signin"
  data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
  data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
  data-clientId="xxxx_client_id"
  data-callback="onSignInCallback"
  data-theme="dark"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
</button>
```

Also gave an link for **Disconnecting Google account from the app**

By clicking the Disconnect button, i am revoking by this link:

https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/revoke?token=xxxxxxxxxxxx

By the access token generated, i am trying to give the access of analytics

https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/ga?ids=ga%3A101373458&start-date=30daysAgo&end-date=yesterday&metrics=ga%3Apageviews%2Cga%3ApageValue%2Cga%3Aentrances&dimensions=ga%3ApagePath%2Cga%3AdaysSinceLastSession%2Cga%3AsessionCount%2Cga%3Abrowser%2Cga%3Acity&filters=ga%3ApagePath%3D%3D%2Finteractive&access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxx

> The user had full permission to access analytics as well.
>
> But after clicking the **Disconnect Button**. User got disconnected
>   from the app and logged out. But when i try to login back, it asks for
>   the necessary permissions to access and he is able to login. But not
>   able to authorize the app.

I also cross checked with:

https://accounts.google.com/IssuedAuthSubTokens

> 1. **MyApp** still exists their and not removed because of disconnect.
> 2. Also checked in google analytics user management, the user still exists for **MyApp**.

I am not passing anything related to app for disconnecting, just deleting the access_token issued. But still how it is been disconnected from the app.

May i know where am i doing wrong?

Comment: did you remember to ask for the Google analytics scope?  https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly

Comment: U mean in the **data-scope** button ? Their is one more user he is able to access analytics. Without passing the scope, he can access it as i have added him in **MyApp **

Comment: some place you cant access Google analytics data without the users permission the user grants permission based upon the scope you send.   If you don't ask for Analytics permissions you cant access analytics data.

Answer (score 1):

Passing additional parameter of https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly to the google plus button as an additional delimeter after referring to this link https://developers.google.com/+/web/signin/reference

```
<button class="g-signin"
  data-scope="https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"
  data-requestvisibleactions="http://schemas.google.com/AddActivity"
  data-clientId="xxxx_client_id"
  data-callback="onSignInCallback"
  data-theme="dark"
  data-cookiepolicy="single_host_origin">
</button>
```